# Angular Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason my factory is not being injected into the controller as expected.

index.html

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/tagFactory.js"></script>
<script src="js/bluetoothFactory.js"></script>
<script src="js/bluetoothController.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
```

tagFactory.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', []).factory('decodeFactory', ['$q', '$window', '$rootScope', function($q, $window, $rootScope) {
//.... this is really empty for now. 
    }])
```

bluetoothFactory.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', []).factory('bluetoothFactory', ['$q', '$window', '$rootScope', function($q, $window, $rootScope) { ... }])
```

bluetoothController.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',[]).controller('bluetoothCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, bluetoothFactory, decodeFactory) {...});
```

When running my page in browser I receive the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: decodeFactoryProvider <-
>   decodeFactory <- bluetoothCtrl

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could potentially be because you're using this syntax more than once: `angular.module('starter.services', [])`.  This is the module `setter` syntax.  You can only call this once, any other times you want to reverence `starter.services` you should call this without the second parameter, like `angular.module('starter.services')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the `starter.services` module twice, which is causing the first one to be overwritten. You either need to give them two different module names or you need to use the getter method, `angular.module('starter.services')`, for the second one.

Comment: That's it. You nailed it. Thank you so much. I have been banging my head over this since the last few hours. I should have asked earlier. Will accept your answer as soon as SO allows me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `bluetoothCtrl` is in `starter.controllers` while `decodeFactory` is in `starter.services` which is not included in the controller's module. Try:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',['starter.services']).controller('bluetoothCtrl', 
    function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, bluetoothFactory, decodeFactory) {...});
```

Comment: But how come that my bluetoothFactory works fine? I just tried it and it doesn't work. Also please note that I am adding the dependencies on the app level in the app.js. Is that correct?

Comment: Matthew Green's answer explains it.